# Android check if network authenticated

Tags: android, authentication, connectivity

I need to check user have connected with CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE so below code give me that result which return isSourceAvailable "true".

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        isSourceAvailable = (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected());
```

but possible he's not authenticated, so I tried with below code but it returns me "COMPLETED" rather it is not authenticated.

```
SupplicantState supplicantState;
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            supplicantState = wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you have to add this

```
 ConnectivityManager CManager =
    (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo NInfo = CManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (NInfo != null && NInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    if (InetAddress.getByName("www.xy.com").isReachable(timeout))
    {  
     // host reachable  true
    }
     else
     {    
     // host not reachable  false
     }  
}
return;
```

Comment: Thanks Himani, but I already try alternative of your answer which by openConnection(), and that is not useful in my case because it is network task.